# Why do I need !important

Tags: css, class, width

I have classes in css

```
.box {
    background-color: white;
    border: solid 5px white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #313131;
    object-fit: fill;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
    background-color: white;
    border: solid 5px white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100px!important;
    height: 100px!important;
    margin-top: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 6px -6px #313131;
    position: relative;
    animation: fadeactive 6s infinite;
}

.box:hover {
    background-color: white;
    border: solid 5px white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 6px -6px #313131;
    object-fit: fill;
    position: relative;
}

.box:hover.active .title {
    display: none!important;
}

.title {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 70%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  top: -40px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 2;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

I use `.box` on some items, and sometimes I use `.active` as well (using both classes). If I do not use `!important`, the box size stays 90px instead of 100px. Also in `.box:hover.active .title` I need to use `!important` to make it work. What did I do wrong? How can I get rid of !important here?

Comment: to override values!

Comment: To override the styles already specified/with more priority.

Comment: it's due to specificity weight. `div.class` as example has a higher specificity as just `.class`. ÌD's`have higher specificity as classes, `div > .class` is also higher then just `.class`... With the code you provided it will not be reproduable

Comment: Because there some class with higher priority, so you should determine with `!important` that which one has the most priority.

Comment: [Specificity-Weigth MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Do not use `!important` ! Only when absolutely necessary as a last resort. Use a more specific selector to overwrite styles.

Answer (score 0):

Here in this example,
Without the !important, the color will be red since ID has most priority.

But since I gave !important to the `span`, it is taking that style.

```css
#item1 {
  color: red;
}

.item {
  color: yellow;
}

span {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<span class='item' id='item1'>hi</span>
```

Comment: thank you. I coudn't use id, since I made the div in js with append from an array. `div.class` made it work.